# Move a UIImageView after applying CGAffineTransformRotate behave incorrect

Tags: ios, uikit, imageview, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to rotate `UIImageView` for certain degrees with `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation()` function, but it end with `imageView` only rotates, but when I moved to another coordinates then imageView stretched or change height and width. I have no clue why this happens.

Here is a code:

```
double a = atan2(dx,dy);
bowImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(a);
```

Comment: You seem to have the wrong order of your arguments to atan2. `y` goes before `x`.

Comment: i do that but it change the rotation angle only.. ... :-(

Answer (score 0):

WHen you apply a transform to a view the geometry changes. If you wish to move that view rotated, the simplest solution is to set the transform back to CGAffineTransformIdentity, move the view and reapply the rotation.

The other way is to work out the movement based on the current rotation.....but I find the first solution easier!

Comment: when i apply CGAffineTransformIdentity than after rotating the ImageView return its initial position.
my problem is that after rotation i want fire the imageView where  rotating position. 
Like Puzzle bubble Game